# How to re-render a heavy React component with a low priority?

Tags: reactjs

With some parameters, I have a React component that can take a few seconds to render but it is not a problem at all if it is not up-to-date.

To prevent the UI from being frozen, I would like to render it only when the user is not changing the form parameters.

It could be a defer, debounce, or another way of doing that. How would you achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: What about the rendering is it, that takes multiple seconds?

Comment: hooks or class?

Comment: could please attach some example or code , there are many ways to defer or prevent cmponents to render

Comment: did you tried to render parts of that component? like if it goes three input views, render/re-render them only when the necessary text is changing

Comment: @trixn It takes like 2-3 seconds with only a special set of parameters I am not sure any user will use. It would not be worth it to optimize it. And it's only a preview so low priority...

Comment: @sojin with hooks :)

Comment: Yeah, you already said that it takes multiple seconds. My question is *why* does it take so long? Are there multiple requests going on or any heavy computation?

Comment: @HDM91 I have tried several ways of doing it but I feel they're all wrong. I would have liked a suggestion to do so. I would like to affect only the rendering. I would prefer to cache the last result instead of displaying a text like 'Loading' if possible. But you're idea to display only the beginning is great in my opinion. How would you re-render the whole component when you know the browser is idling?

Comment: @trixn Heavy computation because it displays a grid. In some cases, the grid could be large, so a lot of resulting divs.

Comment: @AlexisDelrieu Okay, that sounds to me like a use case for a virtualized list or windowing. See e.g. [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized). the idea behind it is that you only render (and therefore progress), what actually fits the screen. Does that reflect your use case?

Comment: @trixn Thanks for the suggestion, it is actually a good idea. Unfortunately, there's an option to zoom out and view the grid as a whole. I don't think virtualization suits this need. :/

Comment: In addition to my current problem, I would be interested in finding a solution to debounce/defer a rendering in React for my own knowledge. I made some researches and I didn't find any "easy" or "proper" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## React 18

With React 18, a new API has been released that lets you mark state updates as less-important *transition updates* (as opposed to normal updates using `useState`/`useReducer`, which are now considered *urgent updates*).

Here's an example:

```
import {startTransition} from 'react';

// Urgent: Show what was typed
setInputValue(input);

// Mark any state updates inside as transitions
startTransition(() => {
  // Transition: Show the results
  setSearchQuery(input);
});
```

See https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-transitions

Another super helpful post with a real world example: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/65

Comment: React 18's transition is definitely the answer to this post. (it was not available at that time though)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`React.lazy and Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) to load the component on demand.

Here I use a flag `loadExtra` to know when to load the extra component, offering a button to load it sooner than the `20 seconds` the `timeout` is set for.

[image: Edit new-dust-066uz]

```
import { ..., lazy, Suspense } from "react";

const ExtraComponent = lazy(() => import("./ExtraComponent"));

const App = () => {
  const [loadExtra, setLoadExtra] = useState(false);

  ...
  <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
    <ExtraComponent />
  </Suspense>;
  ...
};

export default App;
```

I know of this trick, to force a `Component` re-render. By passing the `key` prop to the `Component`, when the key changes, the component will be forced to re-render

So whenever you deem the user is not changing the form, you can change the `key` and the React `Component` will be re-rendered.

Comment: @AlexisDelrieu, I edited my answer, maybe the added info could help answer the question better since you changed the title

Answer (score 1):

You could have an useEffect hook with no depedency array, so it updates every time the component is updated. On the hook, you'll start a timeout or interval to update the state of the component you want to lazy-render. At the return, you'll cancel the timer, which will be restarted at the next effect. That way, every time the form is updated, the rendering of the component is deferred.

Here is a codepen example that works as intended. There is a clock that always updates and the one in the button only updates when you're not interacting with it.

https://codepen.io/bernardofbbraga/pen/powdpqv

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;

const Time = ({ time }) => new Date(time).toLocaleString();

const Clock = () => {
  const timer = React.useRef(null);
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(Date.now());
  React.useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => setTime(Date.now()), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
  });

  return <Time time={time} />;
};

const Lazy = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>
      {" "}
      Counter:{counter}{" "}
      <div>
        This clock only updates when the user is not interacting with the button{" "}
        <Clock />{" "}
      </div>
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    App that updates frequently
    <div>
      <Clock />
    </div>
    <Lazy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```